# No repating in dealing a hand of cards

Tags: duplicates

I need help! I am making a button that will deal out five random cards, however there cannot be any repeating cards. Right now with the code I have below I get the five random cards but there are repeated cards sometimes. How can I edit the code to make there be no repeats? Thank you!

```
enter code here 
"use strict";

var rank = {
"1": "Ace",
"2": "Deuce",
"3": "Tray",
"4": "4",
"5": "5",
"6": "6",
"7": "7",
"8": "8",
"9": "9",
"10": "10",
"11": "Jack",
"12": "Queen",
"13": "King",
};

function getRank(i) {
return rank[i]
};

var suits = {
"1": "Hearts",
"2": "Spades",
"3": "Diamonds",
"4": "Clubs",
};

function getSuit(i) {
return suits[i]
};

var main = function() {

console.log(this.id);

if (this.id == "btn3") {
    var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
    var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
    var random4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1
    var random5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
    var random6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    var random7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
    var random8 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1
    var random9 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1
    var random10 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1
    var output = getRank(random1) + " of " + getSuit(random2) + ", " + getRank(random3) + " of " + getSuit(random4) + ", " + getRank(random5) + " of " + getSuit(random6) + ", " + getRank(random7) + " of " + getSuit(random8) + ", " + getRank(random9) + " of " + getSuit(random10);
    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = output;


var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", main);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Create an array for the entire deck of cards instead of 2 arrays for the rank and suit.  You could create this by making a third variable and looping through the suits for each rank and pushing it to the new deck variable.  Then you generate random numbers from 1-52 and save each one, checking it against the last ones for a duplicate which you would discard.

OR keep what you have and save each card combination (suit and rank random numbers) to test against.

Either way you need to test the second, third, etc. card against the ones already selected.  In the case above, check the combination of random3 and random4 against the combination of random1 and random2.  If both match, generate new values for random3 and random4.